# Split a matrix and save in separate lists or arrays in python?

Tags: python, pandas, matrix

How to create multiple data frames from this in python:

```
c1  c2  c3 ... c50
1   2   33 ... 46
5   8   93 ... 456
6   9   33 ... 456
7   2   32 ... 434
```

I want to create new arrays in this way:  the c1 and c2,  the c1 and c3,  the c1 and c4,  the c1 and c5,  similarly c1 and c50. Each columns group should be save in separate df with the name of the column that change. How can i do in python?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension:

```py
[df[["c1", f"c{i}"]] for i in range(2, 51)]
```

The first two dataframes will look like:

```py
   c1  c2
0   1   2
1   5   8
2   6   9
3   7   2

   c1  c3
0   1  33
1   5  93
2   6  33
3   7  32
```

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to do it.
IIUC that the result will be  DFs. if you need to make an array, you can use append either ".values" or ".to_numpy()" to the end of filter

```
for col in df.columns[1:]:
    vars()['df'+col] = df.filter(['c1',col])
    print(vars()['df'+col])
```

it results in dataframes created by names as dfc1, dfc2, dfc50. That you can access

```
   c1  c2
0   1   2
1   5   8
2   6   9
3   7   2
   c1  c3
0   1  33
1   5  93
2   6  33
3   7  32
   c1  c50
0   1   46
1   5  456
2   6  456
3   7  434
```